# How authenticate listclients request

Tags: icecast

I try to get from PHP the information about the currently connected clients.

```
http://10.0.0.2:8000/admin/listclients?mount=/stream.mpeg
```

but this required an authenfication, which is not possible from a program. So I tried

```
http://10.0.0.2:8000/admin/listclients?mount=/stream.mpeg&user=xyz&pass=wert
```

but Icecast does not accept the user and pass. If I do it inside a browser it works?

In which way I have to provide user and pass?
Or is some additional information required?
Google did not help me.

Comment: HTTP Basic Auth. I'd very much expect even PHP to be able to use that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to put user and pass directlyin the URL. These information has to be base64 encoded and put into the header. Below you find a php example:

```
    $url = "http://www.domain.eu:80004/admin/listclients?mount=/stream.mpeg";
    $user  = "source";
    $pass= "password";
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'    => 'GET',
            'header'    => array ('Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode("$user:$pass"))
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $list1 = file_get_contents($url1, false, $context);
```

You can use the admin password or the source password. I the example I have used the source password.